# How to get GPU information in C?

Tags: c, linux, gpu

I'm writing a C program that needs to determine the GPU model, brand and memory from the host machine. I know it is possible to do that by getting and processing the output of `lshw` but I want to do it in pure C (maybe with libraries).

Is it possible to get GPU information in this way? Are there any libraries that can help achieve this?

EDIT: I'm looking for a linux-specific solution.

Comment: I tagged it as Linux due to your mention of `lshw`, if you are looking for that information for any other OS please clarify. (And I do think the answer will be OS-dependent).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks, I was looking for a linux-specific solution.

Comment: When I wonder how a program does something I look for the source code and find out. https://ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter and https://github.com/lyonel/lshw should give you all the information you need.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Looks like the source code of `lshw` is C++ specific. I wanted a C specific way to do the same thing.

Comment: Perhaps, if you are completely unfamiliar with C++, but I'd bet if you dig deep enough the code that you are looking for is close enough to C to figure out.

Comment: Linux? GPU? Maybe OpenGl? Have a look at: [glGetString](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetString.xhtml). Sure, you'll need a context for that and for the context, you'll need to make a few calls to either EGL or GLX (e.g. [eglIntro](https://registry.khronos.org/EGL/sdk/docs/man/html/eglIntro.xhtml)).

Comment: Unless it's included in the GPU description, I don't think you can get the memory capacity from lspci or lshw. I think you'll need to use an API. I know you can do it with OpenCL, if OpenCL is installed, which it often isn't by default. Similarly, there's CUDA but that is only for Nvidia GPUs. I think your best bet is to go with Erdal's suggestion and see if OpenGL can give you what you need.

Comment: @SimonGoater Since you mentioned OpenCl, maybe we should also add Vulkan to the list (**see:** https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3/html/chap5.html).

Comment: You can use `<pci/pci.h>` to get GPU's name/model, but it does not provide API to get GPU's memory size.